# Flex wrap limit number of rows

Tags: css, angular, sass, responsive-design

My front makes an API request and retrieves a number of items. With these items a flex grid is built, for example like this:

[image]

It is a responsive web and I would like to always have 2 rows, regardless of the width of the screen and hide the remaining items. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Try giving the elements a width of 33.33% so that only 3 elements can fit in a row. This will cause the items to form 2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the :nth-child() selector on the child elements to select everything after the 6th child and set display to none. I am not that familiar with the :nth-child selector, but I made a quick version and it seemed to achieve the desired behaviour with the below CSS.

```
    .flexbox>div:nth-child(n+7) {
        display: none;
    }
```